# React-native dyld error: _AVMetadataObjectTypeDataMatrixCode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, dyld

I've upgraded to react-native 0.16-rc, and tried to run my program on iOS (it worked great on 0.13.2). In simulator all goes great, but when I try to run it on my old iPhone (iOS 7.1 but before it ran great on it) I get error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _AVMetadataObjectTypeDataMatrixCode
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/482E10D8-4B8B-4E1A-8AF8-78AC61C0C398/appname.app/appname
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
 in /var/mobile/Applications/482E10D8-4B8B-4E1A-8AF8-78AC61C0C398/appname.app/appname
```

Can anybody help with it? I use external react-native-camera module which wasn't updated in while. Also didn't have time to  upgraded to newest xCode (my ver. 7.0.1). Anybody had that kind of problems?